# Clone vertex in Titan graph

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin

I'm looking for a way to clone a vertex in a titan graph using groovy code.
What I want to do is to create a new vertex (let's call this vertex y) that contains exactly the same data as another vertex (lets call this vertex x). 
Then I will create a relation to vertex x from vertex y and then delete the previous relation to vertex x.

I know how to get vertex x and how to create/delete relation and add a new vertex.

My only question is, is it possible to clone a vertex and if so, how can this be done using groovy?

Like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blueprints has helper methods to copy the property of one element to another: [copyProperties](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.5.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/ElementHelper.html#copyProperties%28com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Element,%20com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Element%29)

> ```
>  public static void copyProperties(Element from, Element to)
> ```
>
> Copy the properties (key and value) from one element to another. The properties are preserved on the from element. ElementPropertiesRule that share the same key on the to element are overwritten.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> - `from` - the element to copy properties from
> - `to` - the element to copy properties to

Can't think of easier ways to do that offhand.

Comment: There is the same that copy eges too ?